# Filtering for a column value and getting a future warning and a type error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do a simple filter for a df but am getting this error below.

```
df_first = df_b[df_b['label']=='False']
df_second = df_b[df_b['label']=='True']
```

**FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  result = getattr(x, name)(y)**

and

**TypeError: invalid type comparison**

where df_b looks like

```
    id  label
0   92c False
1   f0  False
2   bb  True
```

not sure what I am missing

Thanks!

Comment: The value is a boolean, not a string. You need `df_b[df_b['label'] is False]` and `df_b[df_b['label'] is True]`

Comment: True and False are not strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to compare by boolean `True`, `False`, not string repr of boolean `'True'`, `'False'`:

```
df_first = df_b[df_b['label']==False]
df_second = df_b[df_b['label']==True]
```

What is same like for comapre by `False` only invert mask by `~`, for compare by `True` omit `==True`:

```
df_first = df_b[~df_b['label']]
df_second = df_b[df_b['label']]
```